# Resource not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with accessing a method on my HomeController. I show you the code of the method :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DecriptIdentifiantEtRedirige(string login_crypter, string mdp_crypter)
    {
        string loginAcrypter = _globalManager.ProtegeMotDePasse(login_crypter);
        string MdpAcrypter = _globalManager.ProtegeMotDePasse(mdp_crypter);
        User UserApp = new Models.User(login_crypter, mdp_crypter);
        if (UserApp.AuthentificationValidee(UserApp.UserLogin, UserApp.Password))
        {
            Session["Name"] = UserApp.UserLogin;
            return RedirectToAction("Accueil", "Home");
        }
        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("ValiderAuthentification", "Home");
        }

    }
```

Then in the RouteConfig.cs i wrote the route like that :

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AuthentificationApresDecryptage",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{login_crypter}/{mdp_crypter}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DecriptIdentifiantEtRedirige", login_crypter = "", mdp_crypter = "" }
        );
```

But the problem is that when i try to access that method in the browser with that link:
"http://mydomain.com/DecriptIdentifiantEtRedirige/12345/54321"
It shows me an error : "Resource not found".

Somebody has an idea ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AuthentificationApresDecryptage",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{login_crypter}/{mdp_crypter}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DecriptIdentifiantEtRedirige", login_crypter = UrlParameter.Optional, mdp_crypter = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```